# How do I include js without register/enqueue?

Tags: javascript

I have some js which, rather than register and enqueue, I add directly to a page template.

Currently located outside of WP, I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/js/amplitude/amplitude.js"></script>
```

If I move it to a `js` folder inside my theme, how do I then include it in a template without hardcoding a root-relative path... can I use something like `get_template_directory_uri`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `get_template_directory_uri` to refer to the theme root path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/amplitude/amplitude.js"></script>
```

But prefered way of doing is to use `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Comment: Thanks. I usually register/enqueue, but this adds extra flexibility (and is useful for quick tests of new js).